# About the possessive case with a gerund

Tags: gerunds

Can not every verb (that can be followed followed by a gerund) be followed by the possesive case with a gerund?

As I understand, not every verb that can  precedes a gerund can be followed by the formula (verb+possessive pronoun+ gerund).

E.g It's normal to say "I mind your doing that" but It isn't normal to say "I enjoy your doing it". What's the list of verbs that can be followed by a gerund with the possessive case?

Comment: None of your examples are idiomatic.  It would be more common to hear "I don't like you doing that", "I enjoy you doing that".   You can use "your doing", but [it's quite rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=your+doing+that%2Cyour+doing+it%2C+you+doing+that%2C+you+doing+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) - and to my British ears at least, sounds very old fashioned/stilted.  You are more likely to find it in older books.  There's also an idiomatic expression "your doing" = "your fault".

Comment: What about "I avoid your doing that"? I heard it's not common in English to use a gerund with a possessive pronoun after "avoid ", so I wonder what's the precise list of verbs that can be followed not by just a gerund but a possessive + a gerund

Comment: It's not common in English to use a gerund with a possessive pronoun after "avoid" because ***You** can't "avoid" **me** doing **anything.*** You can ***stop** me doing it*, and you can ***avoid me***, but you can't ***avoid me doing it*** - I think that's more about semantics than "grammar". It's like you can ***Suspect me***, but you can't ***Suspect me/my doing something***, with or without a possessive.

Comment: ...also note that *I like **you doing** that* is a ***verb*** usage. It's only a ***gerund*** use if the verb is being used as a noun - which obviously *must* be the case with the possessive+gerund *I like **your doing** that*.

Comment: @PetroProbka - it's not idiomatic either.  Nobody says these combinations of words. Forget it.  The most common way to use a gerund with a possessive is when it is referring to a skill/activity. For example: Your reading is improving.  My walking has deteriorated since the accident.  Her cooking is terrible.

Comment: Where is it possible to watch the verbs that can be followed by a possessive + a gerund ? For not misusing it

Comment: I don't have easy access to a list, but I can tell you that a great many verbs can take such complements. Grammatically, "I like [you/your doing that]", for example, is OK with either a nominative or genitive pronoun. The only difference is that the genitive is more formal. Note that whichever pronoun is used, the bracketed element is a clause, not a noun phrase.